# Downloading muliple files in background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I was downloading files at a time or one by one or one only according to user requirements. After downloading files I am sending notification to another view as sucessfull message.

When I download a single file at a time it was successfully downloading the file. But when I was trying to download two or more files within time gap of 6 sec (for pressing another download button), first files are not downloading. It downloads only last file which I have send to download.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
url=[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];        
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
   { //Background Thread
       {

       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *dataMain, NSError *error)
        {
            if ([dataMain length]/1024.0f > 600 && error == nil)
            {

                [dataMain writeToFile:pathOriginal atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"orginal file saved");      
            }
        }];
       }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self];
       }); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dispatch async before each call. That way each call will run on a different thread, and will solve your issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can u elaborate it?

Comment: Im in mobile can't post code snippets, but copy this      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated. You should be using `NSURLSession` for new development. An `NSURLSession` will handle multiple downloads. (So would `NSURLConnection`, but it's not worth debugging that given that it's deprecated.

Comment: Good lord, why? That's 4 major releases out of date.

Comment: And Xcode 9 is in Beta, so it will soon be 5 major releases out of date.

Comment: yah I know i was just started and my macbook supports  only xcode 4

Comment: You can only build for iOS 6 using Xcode 4.6. Is your Mac so old that it won't run the current version of OS X? My home mac is a mid 2012 MBP and it runs the latest OS 10 (10.12.6) just fine.

Comment: my mac book just supporting 10.8.